# angular2-webpack-starter - why is string on the left side of equation?

Tags: webpack

In [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) repo, some globals are defined in the DefinePlugin part of webpack, like

`'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV)`.

When this ENV is used in the source files for conditionals, why is string literal on the left side of the equation, like in [vendor.ts](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/src/vendor.ts):

`if ('production' === ENV)` ?

Any difference from `ENV === 'production'`?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a style preference or rendering artifact.  There is no functional difference in the order when comparing two variables.

```
if ('production' === ENV)
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
if (ENV === 'production')
```